# How to get the day, month and year input type in html

Tags: html, forms

[image]

I want to get the input for each - day, month and year. as shown in the figure.

Comment: What do you mean, "input for each individual types"? Like, the input `type` attribute, or the actual input element, or what?

Comment: what i mean is how would you create these input fields, one shown in the image, using html input elements

Comment: @SONGSTER Do you want the style, or just the select values? Also, should it include the label?

Comment: just like in the image, it should give you a select list to chose from the days and if no input is selected it should display current date

Comment: @SONGSTER Check out https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ Not exactly what you asked for, but might be good enough.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion David, as also suggested by Mark I might have to use jquery and css

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a SELECT with all the OPTIONs inside of it, listing all the months and the days.

Be sure to check that some <31> are not shown in some months, and 29-30-31 in February (apart from the year/4 years that still have the 29 in it).

I think you can archive that with some javascript/jquery code, in the end from a front-end perspective, a user doesn't change the day and the month at the same time, so relisting the days after the month is chosen (but keeping the day if it's right) should be not an hard task.

For the arrows and all the graphical stuff you should study css and the webpage css stylesheet in order to have the same result.

Hope it helps, but with no further information, that's the only answer you can receive.